# Activity not started in gingerbread 2.3.3

Tags: android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-fragmentactivity

I am having trouble on opening a new activity from a fragment my activity contain a map fragment v2 .. its working fine on api  4.0  and above .. but I am facing trouble on gingerbread 2.3.3 it gives me a force closed error .

```
public class PerxListDetailFragment extends ListFragment {

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<PerxDetailListModel> datalist ;
protected PerxDetailListAdapter adapter;
protected ListView listview;
protected String url;
protected static String id;
protected static String name;
//JSON names
private static final String TAG_businessId              = "b_id";
private static final String TAG_businessName            = "businessName";
private static final String TAG_businessDescription     = "businessDescription";
private static final String TAG_businessLocation        = "businessLocation";
private static final String TAG_businessAddress         = "businessAddress";


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle      = this.getArguments();
    SharedPreferences user_data = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("userData", 0);

    String bid = user_data.getString("BUSINESSROLEID", null);
    id          = bundle.getString("id");
    name    = bundle.getString("name");

    url     = "http://projects.gaditek.com/mobile/ihirsto/services/getBusiness.php?businessCategoryID="+id +"&businessRole="+bid;

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.perx_list_detail, null, true);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            TextView t = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.perx_list_heading);
            t.setText(name);
            datalist = new ArrayList<PerxDetailListModel>();
            listview = getListView();
            if(datalist.isEmpty()){
                new DownloadData().execute();
            }
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {


                    // Starting new intent
                    String venueName = datalist.get(position).getName().toString();
                    String desc = datalist.get(position).getDescription().toString();
                    String address = datalist.get(position).getAddress().toString();
                    String maplong = datalist.get(position).getlongitude().toString();
                    String maplat = datalist.get(position).getlatitude().toString();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), PerxDetailedActivity.class);


               intent.putExtra("heading", name);
                    intent.putExtra("venueName", venueName);
                    intent.putExtra("desc", desc);
                    intent.putExtra("address", address);
                    intent.putExtra("longitude", maplong);
                    intent.putExtra("latitude", maplat);

               startActivity(intent);



                }


            });

        }


        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack,int transition) 
        {   
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.simple_fragment, fragment, null);
            ft.setTransition(transition);
            if (addToBackStack)
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
```

//=============================

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class PerxDetailedActivity extends Activity{

    String headingName;String venueName;String desc ;String address;
    String latitude;String longitude;

      static LatLng HAMBURG;
      private GoogleMap map;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.perx_detailed);
        Intent intent = new Intent();

         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        headingName = extras.getString("heading");
        venueName   = extras.getString("venueName");
        desc        = extras.getString("desc");
        address     = extras.getString("address");
        longitude   = extras.getString("longitude");
        latitude    = extras.getString("latitude");
        Double longi = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
        Double lati = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
        HAMBURG =  new LatLng(lati, longi);


         map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

         Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                    .title(venueName));


    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);



    }

}
```

Log

```
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gaditek.ihistro/com.gaditek.ihistro.PerxDetailedActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #151: Error inflating class fragment
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #151: Error inflating class fragment
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:224)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1702)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at com.gaditek.ihistro.PerxDetailedActivity.onCreate(PerxDetailedActivity.java:40)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     ... 11 more
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.gaditek.ihistro-1.apk]
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
06-01 18:26:16.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6549):     ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out stupid me the problem lies here

map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

it should be

map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

also as stated by @Glenn activity needs to be extended by FragmentActivity instead Activity
.. hence resolved

Answer (score 3):

Hello it's a compatibility error at :

`E/AndroidRuntime(6549): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.gaditek.ihistro-1.apk] 06-01 18:26:16.546:`

You'r trying to use `Fragment` in your code but to make Fragments works on Gingerbread and under, you have to import a compatibility library from Google : Look here for the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) and this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189630/2084450).

So make sure to turn your `Activity` into `FragmentActivity` and to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

```
 public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack,int transition) 
        {   
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.simple_fragment, fragment, null);
            ft.setTransition(transition);
            if (addToBackStack)
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
```

Comment: I am facing issue on start activity .. i-e PerxDetailedActivity which contian another fragment of map v2 library

Comment: Yeah it's normal, but the Error is not always located at the first line. You have to add the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) to make your app works on Gingerbread.

Comment: yes whole application is using fragments  and is working fine except for this part .... when I need to open a new activity

Comment: Update your post with Edited code (and the imports). Make sure to turn all your `Activiy` into `FragmentActivity`